# Debugger doesn't pause at breakpoints

Tags: php, xdebug, atom-editor

I'm having an issue was hoping I could get some help with configuring Atom and Xdebug. I can set breakpoints and they show up in the breakpoint panel, but the process never pauses. Oddly, the process does pause on a exception warning, so I know it's connecting somewhat, but just not pausing at breakpoints.

My php.ini is as described in the readme:

```
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1    # Not safe for production servers
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_autostart=true
```

Here's my settings:

```
"php-debug":
    PhpException:
      Warning: false
    PathMapping: [
      {
        local: "C:\\wamp\\www\\sgn\\com-forums\\www\\index.php"
        remote: "localhost/sgn/com-forums/www/index.php"
      }
    ]
```

I'm developing locally using WAMP with PHP 5.5.12, xdebug 2.3.5, Atom 1.2.3, & [php-debug](https://github.com/gwomacks/php-debug) 0.1.4. As well, I'm using Chrome with Xdebug helper. What should the idekey be? Any ideas why it isn't working? Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: did you solve the problem? I'm having a similar issue from vagrant

Comment: I ended up just removing all the xdebug options, following the basic example provided with the plugin, restarted everything and it finally worked for me. No idea why.

Comment: and did u restart basically? any service? ur OS?