# IntelliJ debugger does not pause at breakpoints on Maven project

Tags: java, maven, debugging, intellij-idea

**Problem**

Since yesterday, I am unable to launch a proper debug of my tests. Debugger happily jumps over my breakpoints. I validated that the code was actually executed by adding some logs.

**What I've tried so far**

- Synchronize project
- Clean, reinstall and rebuild the project
- Purge Maven dependencies
- Upgrade IntelliJ IDEA to the last version
- Read [IntelliJ docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-debugger-options.html) about configuring debugger options
- Browse questions that had been asked before, with no success (for instance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33883106/debugger-doesnt-pause-at-breakpoints), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30088083/intellij-debugger-does-not-stop-at-breakpoints) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47868117/intellij-debugger-not-working-in-maven-project)).

**More info about the project**

The executed Java code is in one of the folders declared as test sources (one is "java" for Selenium tests, other is "scala" for Gatling tests).

My Maven command line is pretty straightforward: `package clean -Dtest=MyTestClass integration-test`.

**EDIT:** My POM configuration does mention `reuseForks` and `forkCount`. I've also tried playing with deprecated `forkMode`, but with no success.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.20.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <skip>${skip.selenium.tests}</skip>
        <parallel>none</parallel>
        <threadCount>1</threadCount>
        <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
        <forkCount>0</forkCount>
        <disableXmlReport>false</disableXmlReport>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>runSeleniumTests</id>
            <phase>integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>integration-test</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

What is funny, though: debugger actually stops at breakpoints when I right-click on the project root or on test sources root ("java" folder) and click on "Debug 'All tests'".

Any help... will help.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using surefire plugin it runs your test in another process hence you are not able to debug.

Use `forkMode=never` in your maven configuration

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't solve the problem. I've updated my post. Thank you anyway